# Grails 2.3.0 prod war error

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

i'm testing grails 2.3.0 but whe i create the war (prod, test, dev) and try to start tomcat (7.0.42) always get this exception:

```
    2013-09-25 18:23:03,448 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: No signature of method: groovy.xml.streamingmarkupsupport.StreamingMarkupWriter.attributeValue() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.xml.streamingmarkupsupport.StreamingMarkupWriter.attributeValue() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    at grails.spring.DynamicElementReader$_invokeMethod_closure1.doCall(DynamicElementReader.groovy:109)
    at grails.spring.DynamicElementReader.invokeMethod(DynamicElementReader.groovy:117)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:756)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:584)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:527)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

any ideas?

Comment: Can't remember if the same problem. But try JDK 6 instead of 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible you have multiple jar version of the same lib in your grails class path. Try to remove your

```
rm -Rf ~/.grails

rm -Rf ~/.m2 

grails clean

grails run-app
```

If no success try to run a [jarscan](https://java.net/projects/jarscan) on your grails project jars to find duplicate class definitions.

Comment: You are right, after looking onto the exploded war there were groovy-1.8.8 and 2.1.6 jars, i'm using the dependency-report to resolve it.

Comment: Intellij IDEA, Jetbrains IDE, helps this process along by providing prompts for upgrading and keeping track of your different JDKs and Grails versions.